# Force download prompt php broken file

Tags: php, file, header, save, prompt

I have now the current code :

```
if($_POST['mode']=="save") {
    $path = $_POST['path'];
    $file = end(explode('/', $path));
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    readfile($file);
}
```

What i do is, get the path where the file is saved, explode it to only the file name and try to save that file. I do get the save as prompt, but when i save it and try to open the file i get the error message that the file/image is broken.

The files are not saved in the homedirectory but in a subdirectory called uploads.

Someone know what im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.
Sinan

Comment: which is the code for saving the file? Are you sure the file is correctly saved? Before reading the file, have you tried to enclose the readfile() in a is_readable() { ... } ?

Comment: @macjohn I just noticed that my file is not readable. Why not?

Comment: is_readable() returns TRUE if the file or directory specified by filename exists and is readable, FALSE otherwise. Your file not exists, or you have not the permission to read it.

Comment: The file/directory is now readable, but it still fails to display the picture.

Comment: @macjohn The file size which is being saved is correct, the file name is correct but it does not wants to open for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use something like this:

```
$siteEmail = 'me@myemail.com';
$companyName = 'My Company';

#   Path from server root
$fileDirectory = '/home/uploads/'; // include trailing slash

// get the file reference
$passedFile = $_POST['path'];
$filename = @urldecode($passedFile); // useful if your file is sent by $_GET
if((!isset($passedFile))||(@$passedFile=='')) {
    echo "<html><title>".$companyName." - Download File</title><body>ERROR: Please pass a valid filename.<br /><br />Please go back and try again. If you continue to see this message please contact <a href=\"mailto:".$siteEmail."\">".$siteEmail."</a></body></html>";exit();
}

// required for IE, otherwise Content-disposition is ignored
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

if( $filename == "" ) {
  echo "<html><title>".$companyName." - Download File</title><body>ERROR: download file NOT SPECIFIED.<br /><br />Please go back and try again. If you continue to see this message please contact <a href=\"mailto:".$siteEmail."\">".$siteEmail."</a></body></html>";
  exit;
} elseif ( ! file_exists( $fileDirectory . $filename ) ) {
  echo "<html><title>".$companyName." - Download File</title><body>ERROR: File not found.<br /><br />Please go back and try again. If you continue to see this message please contact <a href=\"mailto:".$siteEmail."\">".$siteEmail."</a>
  <p>path: ".$fileDirectory.$filename."</p>
  <p>DOCUMENT_ROOT: ".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."</p>
  </body></html>";
  exit;
};

switch( $file_extension ) {
  case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
  case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
  case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
  case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
  case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
  case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
  case "rtf": $ctype="application/rtf"; break;
  case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
  case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
  case "wav": $ctype="audio/wav"; break;
  case "mp3": $ctype="audio/mpeg3"; break;
  case "wmv": $ctype="video/x-ms-wmv"; break;
  case "avi": $ctype="video/avi"; break;
  case "asf": $ctype="video/x-ms-asf"; break;
  case "mpg": $ctype="video/mpeg"; break;
  case "mpeg": $ctype="video/mpeg"; break;
  case "jpeg":
  case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
  default: $ctype="application/force-download";
}

// Everything went fine - you could log the download in the databse here if required?

// OUTPUT THE FILE

header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // cache stop
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); // cache stop
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate"); // cache stop
header("Content-Type: $ctype"); // output filetype
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($fileDirectory.$filename));
readfile($fileDirectory.$filename);
exit();
```